# How can I allow users to easily share a download link for my app?

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can I communicate the download link from one user who has it to one who does not? 
If all they have are their android phones. Bluetooth?  Would I send a contact card.

Are there less cumbersome ways that pairing?

Comment: Might try displaying a QR code the other person can scan.

Answer (score 5):

Look for the share intent. [Here](http://androidforums.com/application-development/98031-share-intent.html)'s an example:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Some text");
shareIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Some other text");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Title for chooser"));
```

Comment: Could you explain. How does it know who it's sharing the intent to? I'm attempting phone to phone communication.

Comment: @Arian: Try that out. If you have a bluetooth app in your device it will give you the opportunity of sharing through it.